Round off 0.998 to 2 sig fig
I have a question about sig fig…
When round off 0.998 to 2sig fig, the first and second are 9.in addition 8>5 therefore , we need add 0.01 to to 0.99 to get the nearest hundredth. Should we write the answer 1.00? Or 1.0 instead?
The point got me confuesd is that 1.00 have 3 sig fig now…
If we write 1.00(corr to 2 sig fig),it means the actual value is between 0.995 and 1.005.
If we write 1.0(corr to 2 sig fig), it means the actual value is between 0.95 and 1.05.
What do you guys think? What if the question is in a physic class or chemistry class ?

Ambiguities are always annyoing , I would interprete it as two digits after the decimal point- In the floating point arithmetic it would rather be $1.0$ instead.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I would say it depends entirely on the pre-established rules of significant figures (which do vary).

@Peter: If you want two digits after the decimal point, you have to say two decimal places. Two significant figures gives $1.0$ here.

It may be helpful to think about significant digits in two ways. 1: An instrument or assay has an inherent limit in its precision, often expressed as an operating range and a standard deviation within that range, like $\pm b$. If b is in the hundredths place, your significant digits extend only to that place. 2: In a formula, no matter how precise some measures, the least precise measure dictates the overall precision, so you perform the computation and truncate to the least known precision, in your case I would have 1.0.

If you're rounding something to a certain number of significant figures, the only thing that matters is the final number you come out with so the answer to rounding 0.9999 to 2s.f. is 1.0.
When you're rounding all you're concerned about is getting the final number to 2 s.f. and so we make a guess that normally we're going to need to just get rid of all of the numbers after that and either bump the 2nd digit up or down by 1. In this case however, it's not so simple and while you make your initial guess that you need to change the 2nd digit you also end up changing the first 0 to a 1. What this means is that instead of removing all of the digits after the hundredth place to turn to 2 s.f. you need to get rid of all of them after the tenth place. This is why it's not so much about finding a number to add on like 0.01 but rather first rounding up to the number you want (i.e. getting to 1.0000) and then removing all of the later decimal places you don't want (so ending up with 1.0).
Also, maths is universal and a subject of its own, so it doesn't matter if you're in physics, chemistry, or history: the answer will always be the same.
Hope this helps :)

Leading and trailing zeros are ignored when rounding to significant figures, so we can essentially ignore the decimal point and look at your number in scientific notation, $0.998=9.98\times10^{-1}$. Through the lens of scientific notation, to round to $n$ SF, we usually round the $n$'th digit of the coefficient and keep only its first $n$ digits when that is re-expressed in scientific notation. Hence $9.98\times10^{-1}\to10.0\times10^{-1}\to1.0\times10^{0}$.

I think when your rounding $0.998$ to $2$ significant figures, you must first identify what is significant and what is not.
$0$ is NOT a significant figure because it's directly left to the decimal point.
The first $9$ ($0.9$) is significant because it's a non zero number
The second $9$ ($0.09$) is significant because it's a non zero number too
Lastly, the third $9$ ($0.008$) is significant because it's a non zero number also
So, basically, I'm rounding to the $2$nd decimal point because $9$ and $9$ are the first and second significant figure. Therefore, I'm rounding to the $2$nd decimal place: $0.998$, which equals to $1.00$, and you have to put the two zeros at the back because that shows the $2$ decimal places.
Hope this answers your question!

No, the final answer has to contain just two significant figures. So $1.0$.

It has to be $1.00$ because $1.0$ has only $1$ significant figure as the $0$ is directly to the right of the decimal point.

@WashingtonFig, 1.00 is 3 significant figures.

@WashingtonFig, it's leading zeroes that dont count as significant figures, not trailing zeroes. So $0.0012$ has two significant figures, but $12.00$ has four.
